# JSF - iFrame src attribute does not match HTML display

Tags: html, jsf, iframe, primefaces

I have an iFrame in my page looking like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="gameDiv">
    <f:verbatim>
        <iframe src="/levelup/resources/#{cc.attrs.src_dir}/#{cc.attrs.src_html}"     width="700px" height="800px" frameborder="0" id="gameFrame">
         </iframe>
    </f:verbatim>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Basically, the "src" variable is bound using JSF 2.0 EL, and gets its value from a backing bean.

I then use a form to update this value, and refresh the whole page. In the rendered HTML, I can see that the "src" for my div has been updated. However, the HTML page still shows the old one.

I thought the issue was similar to [2 iframes with the same display even if the src are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731381/2-iframes-with-the-same-display-even-if-the-src-are-different), and I tried the solutions that have been mentioned (using a timestamp to make the src unique, or resetting them to "about:blank" on each page load). None of them worked however.

For information, the form that updates the backing bean is:

```
<h:form id="gameSelectionForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="gameSelection">
        <f:selectItems value="#{gameBean.gameIds}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton id="gameSelector" action="#{gameBean.changeGame}" update="gameScoreFieldset, gameDiv" />
</h:form>
```

Any hint would be much useful.

Thanks in advance,
Sébastien

Comment: The issue seems to be on FireFox; it works properly on Chrome and IE.

Comment: And removing the "f:verbatim" tag does not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing the `src` of the `iframe` using JS/Ajax, but not reloading its content.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

- Just don't use JS/ajax. A synchronous HTTP request will reload the entire document and thus automagically reload the `iframe`.

  ```
  <p:commandButton ajax="false" />
  ```
- Use JS to force reload. Add the following *after* the `<iframe>`.

  ```
  <script>document.getElementById('gameFrame').location.reload()</script>
  ```

---

Oh, you *definitely* need to remove the `<f:verbatim>`. Since JSF 1.2 that tag is [utterly useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502465/jsf-mybean-mygetter-called-before-form-submission/4527126#4527126).

Comment: Combination of both modifications worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even using only ajax=false did the trick. Inserting only the script inside the <iframe></iframe> tags would not work however.